# formatting xml with xmltextwriter

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, xmlwriter

I am creating xml docs using xmltextwriter ( by the way I was just introduced to xslt which I am now learning to adopt rather) and having problems getting the xml to indent correctly.

Here is what I would like the format to be

```
<htmltext> CData[.......<br>
   <img  src=".......">
   <a href="........"</a><br>
   ...some text here from a string....<br>
   ...some other text here froma string>
</htmltext>
```

here is what I have tried:

```
xwriter.WriteStartElement("htmltext")
xwriter.WriteCData(hcontent)
xwriter.WriteElementString("", "<br>")
xwriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine)
xwriter.Indentation = 2
xwriter.WriteElementString("img", "")
xwriter.WriteStartAttribute("src", himage)
xwriter.WriteEndAttribute()
xwriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine)
xwriter.WriteElementString("a", "")
xwriter.WriteStartAttribute("href", hlinks)
xwriter.WriteEndAttribute()
xwriter.WriteElementString("", htitle)
xwriter.WriteElementString("", "<br>")
xwriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine)
xwriter.WriteElementString("", hsubtitle)
xwriter.WriteElementString("", "<br>")
xwriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine)
xwriter.WriteElementString("", htext)
xwriter.WriteEndElement()
```

not sure where to go from here. Appreciate any responses

Comment: You should not use `XmlTextWriter`. It has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. You should use `XmlWriter.Create` to create an `XmlWriter`.

Comment: ok then how do you do the formatting for indentation when formatting is not part of it

Comment: Mainly, just don't bother with formatting. It's not important. If you need formatting, use the settings in the `XmlWriterSettings`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround and just converted all into a string.